# Von Neumann–Morgenstern: compare coefficients in Archimedean axiom

Tags: axioms, economics, decision-theory, utility

Now we have:

- Axiom1: Completeness of $\succeq$.
- Axiom2: Transitivity of $\succeq$.
- Axiom3: Independence: For any $N$ and $p\in (0,1]$, if $L\succ M$, then $pL+(1-p)N\succ pM+(1-p)N$.
- Axiom4: Archimedean: if $L\succ M \succ N$, then there exists $\alpha, \beta\in(0,1)$ such that $\alpha L+(1-\alpha)N \succ M \succ \beta L+(1-\beta)N$.

**Given these four axioms, how to prove that $\alpha>\beta$?** By independence axiom we can only get preference relationship $\succ$ between lotteries, but not any numerical relationship $>$ between coefficients. Then how to get this between $\alpha, \beta$?

A dual problem would be, given coefficients $\alpha, \beta\in[0,1]$, $\alpha>\beta$, and preference $L\succ M$, **how to prove that $\alpha L+(1-\alpha)M \succ \beta L+(1-\beta)M$?**

I tried to construct intermediate lotteries to leverage Independence Axiom, but always failed at the gap between $\succ$ and $>$. Any suggestion on how to use coefficient relationship $>$ would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the dual problem:

If $L\succ M$ and $\alpha\in (0,1)$ then by Ax3,
$$L\,=\,\alpha L+(1-\alpha)L\,\succ\, \alpha L+(1-\alpha)M\,\succ\,\alpha M+(1-\alpha)M\,=\,M \,.$$

If also $\beta\in (0,\alpha)$ is given, then applying the same once again to $N:=\alpha L+(1-\alpha)M\,\succ M$ and $\gamma:=\frac\beta\alpha\in (0,1)$ we get
$$N\,\succ\,\gamma N+(1-\gamma)M\,=\,\beta L+(1-\beta)M\,.$$
Swapping the role of $\alpha,\beta$ shows that if $\alpha<\beta$ then $\alpha L+(1-\alpha)M \prec \beta L+(1-\beta)M$, so it ensures $\alpha>\beta$ in Ax4.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have two questions:
1. In (1), what does it mean by a lottery $\succ 0$? What does "$0$" mean here? A null lottery? 
2. In (2), How to arrive at $(\alpha-\beta)L\succ (\alpha-\beta)M$? If it's independence axiom, where's the second term $(1-\alpha+\beta)N$ for some $N$?
3. In (2), can shift in algebraic equation (move a term from one side to another) also be applied to compound lotteries?

Comment: By "shift in equation", in other words I am asking the minus ("$-$") operation in e.g. $\alpha L - \beta L$. Is the minus a legal operation here? How to see it from Axioms?

Comment: Sorry, I had some other things of vonNeumann in mind when answering.
Now I updated my answer, I hope it's correct now.